# How to use static conf in CSS?

Tags: python, django

How to use static conf in CSS?

```
body {
        background: url('static/img/body.png');
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        font-family: Georgia,"Bitstream Charter",serif;
      }
```

This not working.

My static conf:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/domains/domain/public_html/website/website/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/home/user/domains/domain/public_html/website/website/static/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Paths inside of your CSS file are relative, so you don't need to set static at all in the CSS file.

For example:

Your stylesheet is located at `/home/user/domains/domain/public_html/website/website/static/stylesheet.css`

Assuming your file structure is:

```
-- /static
-- -- stylesheet.css
-- -- -- /img
-- -- -- -- body.png
```

You can simply define your body as:

```
body {
        background: url('img/body.png');
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        font-family: Georgia,"Bitstream Charter",serif;
      }
```

And call your stylesheet in your HTML via:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_ROOT }}stylesheet.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Your `STATIC_URL` should be a url (i.e. `static.yourdomain.com/your_application/` or similar), that looks like a path on your filesystem so it won't work.

Normally a relative url in your css files should work just fine.

And don't forget to run `manage.py collectstatic`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic